# What Versions of MS does Artifactory Support?

Tags: tfs, artifactory, project.json

I am looking for some more specific support details.

I have managed to persuade our management to use Artifactory.

We currently use the following, mostly for WinForms development.  We have several dozen products we support.

Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise
TFS 2012 on Prem (working to  persuade management to upgrade this soon)
NuGet 3.5. with Project.JSon

I am just not sure if Artifactory can support some of the older tools we use.  I can't find any details on their website that are version specific.  It just says it supports "TFS".

I read mention in some samples of Packages.config, but we got rid of those bad boys some time ago.  Project.json is much better.  Once we move to VS 2017 the project.json goes away too.

Does Artifactory support TFS 2012?  Project.Json files?

Answer (score 1):

Artifactory [NuGet](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/NuGet+Repositories) support is agnostic of how you manage your project, the only requirement is that your builds use supported clients (like the one integrated into VS). You can deploy and resolve your own packages or have Artifactory proxy a remote location (as long as it supports the NuGet API)

TFS support is provided by the [MSBuild Artifactory Plugin](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/MSBuild+Artifactory+Plugin#MSBuildArtifactoryPlugin-TeamFoundationServer(TFS)Integration) which collects [info](https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Build+Integration) from your build and also enables you to resolve dependencies via Artifactory, and deploy build artifacts.

Answer (score 0):

If you are on TFS2012, it's still using XAML build. Which means you need to use MSBuild Artifactory Plugin.

> The MSBuild Artifactory Plugin is installed as a "**Project
>   Template**" using Visual Studio as follows:
>
> - Under Tools, choose Extensions and Updates..., select the Visual    Studio Gallery source under the Online section,  and run a search for 
>     "Artifactory".
> - Select Artifactory Template Package extension found, and click   Install.

So, instead of TFS version limitation, it should be more related to VS version.
And according to the [Artifactory Template Package](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JFrog-inc.ArtifactoryTemplatePackage-18102) in VisualStudio Marketplace, which including VS2015.

[image]